# How to get vehicle speed from CarPlay SDK?

Tags: carplay

I don't want to use GPS or accelerometer to get the vehicle speed. Does the CarPlay SDK make this available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can not interface with a car internals using CarPlay SDK.

Comment: Entertainment systems are usually encapsulated and completely separated from internal systems. If you are interested in vehicle speed, you may want to work with an OBD2 interface.